# TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer) when passing 'params'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, parameters, ruby-on-rails-5

First - Apologies in advance. I realize there are other posts on this issue, but I am very new to development and need a more thorough understanding and explanation.

The issue is that I am getting a `TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer)` error when sending `params` as part of a `.where` query.

I have a Twilio integration, and when I receive a text from a phone number, I want to look up that phone number in the `Users` table in my database to see if they exist, then do some action.

Here are the parameters I'm seeing in the console which I'm getting from the POST call from Twilio (I removed sensitive or irrelevant ones):

```
Parameters: {"SmsStatus"=>"received", "Body"=>"Blah blah blah", "From"=>"+15555555555"}
```

And here is the controller method which is getting hit:

```
    def incoming_text
        user = User.where(phone: params[:From])
        if user.present?
            url = URI.extract(params[:Body])
            if url.present?                             ### Row #26
        end
    end
```

Based on the other threads I've read, I believe the issue is with how I'm passing `params[:From]`, but I just don't know what the data structure or notation is for how I *should* be passing it. Any documentation I should read up on would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** Here is the schema for my `users` table:

```
  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "phone"
    t.boolean "confirmed"
  end
```

**EDIT2:** The real issue appears to be unrelated to this. I am still investigating, but I do not want to waste anyone else's time.

**EDIT3:** Here are the logs:

```
User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."phone" = ?  [["phone", "+15555555555"]]
#<User:0x00007efcedb05400>
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)

TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer):

app/controllers/users_controller.rb:26:in `incoming_text'
```

Comment: Is that the whole `params` object? It seems is an array instead of a hash, what does `params.keys` return?

Comment: @SebastianPalma Here are the keys:
ToCountry  
ToState  
SmsMessageSid  
NumMedia  
ToCity  
FromZip  
SmsSid  
FromState  
SmsStatus  
FromCity  
Body  
FromCountry  
To  
ToZip  
NumSegments  
MessageSid  
AccountSid  
From  
ApiVersion  
controller  
action

Comment: Can you add the logs, at the moment of the request?

Comment: @SebastianPalma Updated. Please also read my second edit which I posted just before you. I think I was looking at (a) the wrong issue (there is a 500 error, but I'm not sure why), and (b) the `TypeError` seems to happen on another row which I didn't previously include. I have now included it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your database column `phone` is of the type `Integer`, have you tried casting `params[:From]` to an Integer?

Updated, it would look like:

```rb
    def incoming_text
        user = User.where(phone: params[:From].to_i)
        if user.present?
            ...
        end
    end
```

`.to_` will automatically strip the "+" sign also

Comment: I've edited my original post with my schema. It shows `phone` is a `string`.

Comment: Somehow you've gotten a nested array (see the double sqaure brackets around the array in the first line of your logs).
If you want it to work without figure out why the params are coming in how they are you can do this: `params[:From][0][1]`